# Is there any in built calendar view in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to invoke a calendar as the calendar application does in iPhone. Is there any inbuilt framework which will help or we have to built the whole calendar on our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in calendar framework for the iPhone. Additionally, you can't access a users calendars as with the address book or iPod.

There are some 3rd party solutions:

http://code.google.com/p/iphonecal/

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/

Comment: And of course you should file a radar bug requesting this functionality in the SDK.

Comment: radar bug rdar://7237391 filed today. has anyone else heard any news about this?

Comment: @Corey Floyd How can we get Event Color from iphone-gcal-example ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below link. This may help you...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634000/is-there-a-calendar-control-we-can-use-for-iphone-apps`